# BeautifulSoup to extract the text from a [br] to a [table]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am scraping a school course calendar,i meet some problems when i try to extract the exclusion of each course.(the web i am scraping:http://www.apsc.utoronto.ca/Calendars/2014-2015/Course_Descriptions.html#ACT240H1)

the exclusion is the part from the [br] to the last [a] before the [table] as the code shown below:

```
<br>Exclusion:

                MGT438H1(br)
 <a name="ECE460H1"></a>
<br>



<a name="ACT460H1"></a>

<table border="0" width="100%">
```

I want the result to be something like this:
    "Exclusion:MGT438H1,
    ECE460H1
    "

while my code below prints all the text from the [br] I start to the end the website.

(I want to get the text from the 'br' to the last 'a' not including the last 'a''s text("ACT460H1") before the [table], is there a way to do that?)

the following is the code I write to get the text between the [br] to [a]:

```
nextATag = ccpre.find_next('table')

def loopUntilA(text, firstElement):

    if isinstance(firstElement, str):
        text += firstElement
    elif type(firstElement) is Tag:
        text += firstElement.text
    if (firstElement.next.next == nextATag):             
        return text
    else:
    #Using double next to skip the string nodes themselves
        return loopUntilA(text, firstElement.next.next)
targetString = loopUntilA('', ccpre)

print(targetString)
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are still asking. Try cleaning up the question (code formatting) and stating exactly what you want the results to be. Since this is your first question, feel free to ask for tips here!

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at other people's questions and modified my question a bit.